# module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'davies_bouldin_score'

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, evaluation, google-colaboratory

I am trying to evaluate a clustering kmeans model using sklearn.metrics.davies_bouldin_score. I am using google colab with runtime Python 3 and GPU accelerator.

I got this error:
module 'sklearn.metrics' has no attribute 'davies_bouldin_score'.
[image: image of the error]

I have tried to import metrics package in different ways as it was suggested by some people as `from sklearn import metrics` and `import sklearn.metrics`. It made no difference.

I have also updated sklearn package `!pip install --upgrade sklearn` and it did not solve the problem.

Is it google-colaboratory? How can I solve it?

Comment: What *version* do you have? That will likely answer your question...

Answer (score 1):

You need to `pip install scikit-learn`, not `sklearn`, though the `import sklearn.metrics` is correct. It looks like it's also a recently added feature, so it may not be available in earlier versions of scikit-learn.

Answer (score 1):

It is in version 0.20. Make sure you are using the right version of Sklearn. 
"conda update sklearn"